# Objeto no se renderiza por completo en React y muestra una longitud que no concuerda con el tamaño real del mismo

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Estoy teniendo problema con el renderizado de un objeto en React. Por algún motivo, de 5 elementos que tiene, sólo me renderiza 3. Lo he comprobado en consola, y me ocurre lo siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Por algún motivo inicialmente me aparece que el array tiene 3 elementos, pero si lo despliego me aparecen 5. Justamente los elementos que se renderizan son los 3 primeros. Dejo también el componente de React por si pudiera ser de ayuda:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

import './RegisterBlock.css';

const RegisterBlock = () => {

    const [gamertag, setGamerTag] = useState("");
    const [password, setPassword] = useState("");
    const [repassword, setRepassword] = useState("");
    const [mail, setMail] = useState("");
    const [isChecked, setIsChecked] = useState(false);
    const [errors, setErrors] = useState(null);

    const handleChange = (event) => {
        event.target.name === "password" ? setPassword(event.target.value) : 
            event.target.name === "repassword" ? setRepassword(event.target.value) : 
            event.target.name === "gamertag" ? setGamerTag(event.target.value) : 
            event.target.name === "email" ? setMail(event.target.value) : setIsChecked(!isChecked) ;
    }

    const handleSubmit = (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();

        var totalErrors = [];

        if (gamertag.length === 0 || gamertag.length > 30) {
            totalErrors.push({"error": "La contraseña debe tener entre 2 y 30 caracteres"});
        }

        if (!/^[a-zA-Z0-9]+@[a-zA-Z0-9]+\.[A-Za-z]+$/.test(mail)) {
            totalErrors.push({"error": "Introduce un correo válido"});
        }

        if (!isChecked) {
            totalErrors.push({"error": "Debes aceptar haber leído las políticas para poder registrarte"});
        }

        const url = "URL API" + mail;
        fetch(url)
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(data => {
                data.length > 0 && totalErrors.push({"error": "Ya hay una cuenta con este correo"});
            });

        const urlGamertag = "URL API" + gamertag;
        fetch(urlGamertag)
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(data => {
                data.length > 0 && totalErrors.push({"error": "El gamertag ya ha sido usado por otro usuario"});
            });

        setErrors(totalErrors);
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        if (errors?.length === 0) {
            const requestOptions = {
                method: 'POST',
                headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
                body: JSON.stringify({ 
                    name: gamertag,
                    password: password,
                    email: mail
                })
            };
            fetch('URL API', requestOptions)
                .then(response => response.json())
        }  
    }, [errors?.length === 0])

    return (
        <div className="login-block">
            <div className="wrapper">
                <form onSubmit={handleSubmit} method="post">
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Gamertag" name="gamertag" value={gamertag} onChange={handleChange}/>
                    <input type="mail" placeholder="Email" name="email" value={mail} onChange={handleChange}/>
                    <input type="password" placeholder="Contraseña" name="password" value={password} onChange={handleChange}/>
                    <input type="password" placeholder="Verifica contraseña" name="repassword" value={repassword} onChange={handleChange}/>
                    <div className="form__checkbox">
                        <input onChange={handleChange} name="policy" id="policy" type="checkbox" checked={isChecked} />
                        <label htmlFor="policy">Al registrarte confirmas haber leído la <Link to="/politica-de-privacidad">Política de privacidad</Link> y Aviso legal.</label>
                    </div>
                    {console.log(errors)}
                    {
                        errors?.length > 0 && (
                            <ul className="form--errors">
                                {
                                    errors.map((item, index) => {
                                        return <li key={index}>{item.error}</li>
                                    })
                                }
                            </ul>
                        )
                    }
                    <input type="submit" value="Registrarse"/>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>  
    )
}

export default RegisterBlock;
```

Comment: Me parece que el problema es que estás haciendo el `.push` al array `totalErrors` dentro de los `fecth`. Aparentemente no se puede actualizar un array dentro de una promesa que fue definido afuera de esta. En esta pregunta en inglés se da una posible solución a ese problema: [How to push data from fetch() to array in Javascript using a for loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61618627/how-to-push-data-from-fetch-to-array-in-javascript-using-a-for-loop)

Answer (score 0):

Podrías intentar mover  a *setErrors(totalErrors)* al fetch(urlGamertag) para que  tome el valor más reciente retornado de la promesa.

```
fetch(urlGamertag)
   .then(response => response.json())
   .then(data => {
       data.length > 0 && totalErrors.push({"error": "El gamertag ya ha sido usado por otro usuario"});
       setErrors(totalErrors) // aqui
    });

 /* setErrors(totalErrors); // mover arriba  */
```

Saludos!

Answer (score 0):

#### Promise All

El patrón recomendado para cuando hay mas de una operación asincrónica de tipo `fetch API`, como en este caso, es usar `promise.all` esto garantiza lo siguiente:

- La resolución de cada una de las promesas involucradas.
- El orden en que se ejecutan las operaciones asincronicas

En el siguiente demo, se implementa una solución muy parecida al caso de uso:

```js
function App(){
  const [error, setError] = React.useState();

  function handle_async(){
    let totalErrors=[];
    
    totalErrors.push({"error":"uno"})
    totalErrors.push({"error":"dos"})
    totalErrors.push({"error":"tres"})
    
    const p1 = fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts")
      .then((res) => res.json())
    const p2 = fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts")
      .then((res) => res.json())
  
    Promise.all([p1, p2]).then(values => {
       //extraes el valor que necesites evaluar con if
       //para cada elemento en values, que es el resultado de 
       //su correspondiente promesa
       //console.log(values[0].length); 
       //console.log(values[1].length);
       totalErrors.push({"error":"cuatro"});
       totalErrors.push({"error":"cinco"});
       setError(totalErrors);
    });

    //console.log(totalErrors);
   }
   //console.log(error);
   return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={handle_async}>Click me</button>
         <pre>{JSON.stringify(error, null, 2)}</pre>
     </div>)
  }

  ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('root'))
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.development.js" crossorigin ></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.development.js" crossorigin ></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

---

#### Soluciones con problemas race condition fecth API

Async race condition:

- No hay garantía de la resolución de las operaciones asincronicas.
- Si hay `n` operaciones asincronicas, la secuencia de ejecución es incierta.

`fetch API` tiene su propio Memory allocation además, es posible crear `trailing closure` sobre variables declaradas  (`totalErrors`) en el `outter scope` (`handleSubmit`) y modificar sus valores en consecuentes llamadas a `fecth`; siempre y cuando estas llamadas consecutivas esten en el mismo outter scope, justo como en este caso.

Sin embargo, la siguiente solución es propensa a errores de tipo `async race condition`:

```js
function App(){
  const [error, setError] = React.useState();

  function handle_async(){
    //ReactJS: handle scope esta en mi memory space
    let totalErrors=[];
    //todas las operaciones push en este scope
    //afectan a las vars de mi memory space
    totalErrors.push({"error":"uno"})
    totalErrors.push({"error":"dos"})
    totalErrors.push({"error":"tres"})
    //fetch es una operacion async
    //crea otro memory space
    //necesito continuar el programa
    //dentro de ese memory space
    //para eso uso la funcion de continuacion then
    fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts")
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((data) => {
        //fetch API: registro nueva variable
        //en este scope, toralErrors
        //esta operacion push no se realiza
        //en el scope de react
        //solo en el scope de fecth API
        //ademas forma un trailing closure
        //con el parent scope, donde ya tiene
        //3 valores asignados
        totalErrors.push({"error":"cuatro"});
      });
    fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts")
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((data) => {
       //fetch API: registro nueva variable
        //en este scope, toralErrors
        //esta operacion push no se realiza
        //en el scope de react
        //solo en el scope de fecth API
        //ademas forma un trailing closure
        //con el parent scope, donde ya tiene
        //3 valores asignados
        totalErrors.push({"error":"cinco"});
        //actualizo el estado de errors en reactjs
        //termina pasa el nuevo valor de errors
        //a reactJS que devolvera el componente nuevamente
        setError(totalErrors);
       
      });

    //console.log(totalErrors);
  }
  //console.log(error);
  return (
    <div>
    <button onClick={handle_async}>Click me</button>
    <pre>{JSON.stringify(error, null, 2)}</pre>
    </div>
  )
}

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('root'))
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.development.js" crossorigin ></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.development.js" crossorigin ></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Nótese que al dar click en el botón varias veces, en algunas se omite el valor `{"error":"cuatro"}`.

---

Ahora, puede que la situación demostrada anteriormente se resuelva, si se usa el setter de `useState` en el `fetch` donde se realiza el `push` de `{"error":"cuatro"}`:

```js
function App(){
  const [error, setError] = React.useState();

  function handle_async(){
    //ReactJS: handle scope esta en mi memory space
    let totalErrors=[];
    //todas las operaciones push en este scope
    //afectan a las vars de mi memory space
    totalErrors.push({"error":"uno"})
    totalErrors.push({"error":"dos"})
    totalErrors.push({"error":"tres"})
    //fetch es una operacion async
    //crea otro memory space
    //necesito continuar el programa
    //dentro de ese memory space
    //para eso uso la funcion de continuacion then
    fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts")
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((data) => {
        //fetch API: registro nueva variable
        //en este scope, toralErrors
        //esta operacion push no se realiza
        //en el scope de react
        //solo en el scope de fecth API
        //ademas forma un trailing closure
        //con el parent scope, donde ya tiene
        //3 valores asignados
        totalErrors.push({"error":"cuatro"});
        //actualizo el estado de errors en reactjs
        //termina pasa el nuevo valor de errors
        //a reactJS que devolvera el componente nuevamente
        setError(totalErrors);
      });
    fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts")
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((data) => {
       //fetch API: registro nueva variable
        //en este scope, toralErrors
        //esta operacion push no se realiza
        //en el scope de react
        //solo en el scope de fecth API
        //ademas forma un trailing closure
        //con el parent scope, donde ya tiene
        //3 valores asignados
        totalErrors.push({"error":"cinco"});
        //actualizo el estado de errors en reactjs
        //termina pasa el nuevo valor de errors
        //a reactJS que devolvera el componente nuevamente
        setError(totalErrors);
       
      });

    //console.log(totalErrors);
  }
  //console.log(error);
  return (
    <div>
    <button onClick={handle_async}>Click me</button>
    <pre>{JSON.stringify(error, null, 2)}</pre>
    </div>
  )
}

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('root'))
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.development.js" crossorigin ></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.development.js" crossorigin ></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Pero no, ahora al dar click en el botón en varias ocasiones, se puede ver `{"error":"cuatro"}` y `{"error":"cinco"}`, o tal vez solo `{"error":"cuatro"}` y viceversa, el resultado de las operaciones `fetch` tampoco llegan siempre en el mismo orden en que fueron declaradas.

[promise.all](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all)